# Cannot resolve symbol InstantTaskExecutorRule

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit4, rx-java2

I open example code BasicRxJavaSample (from this article [Room+RxJava](https://medium.com/google-developers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757)) 
The main thing is there:

```
@Rule
public InstantTaskExecutorRule instantTaskExecutorRule = 
    new InstantTaskExecutorRule();
```

And BasicRxJavaSample is all ok.
But I can not apply this in my test.
That's what's going on:

***Cannot resolve symbol InstantTaskExecutorRule***

[image]

And manual import does not work:

[image]

My autocompletion works like this
[image]

But should be so

[image]

My app build.gradle ([full gradle here](https://gist.github.com/tim4dev/b95f36ccd2f32d0603457a281ef6bf58)):

```
// tests
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportVersion"
testImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:$archVersion"
// Test helpers for Room
testImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.0.0"
// https://github.com/mockito/mockito
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.13.0'
androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.13.0'
// AndroidJUnitRunner and JUnit Rules
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
// https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/packages.html
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.0.1'
```

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Replace testImplementation by androidTestImplementation. So the tests on folder androidTest can have access to the library.

```
dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
}
```

> If you are not using **androidx** then use `android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1`

Comment: I have made the above changes but this solution didn't work in my case. Is there any other possibility?

Comment: @Kavita_p I changed `androidTestImplementation` to `testImplementation`, then it resolved and worked

Comment: If doesn't work after provided dependencies. Add manually 
`import androidx.arch.core.executor.testing.InstantTaskExecutorRule`

Answer (score 82):

I know it's late but I would like to add one thing to this accepted answer.

If you want to use,

```
@Rule
public InstantTaskExecutorRule instantTaskExecutorRule = 
new InstantTaskExecutorRule();
```

in your **JUnit** test case, i.e., in **test folder** then use following dependency, i.e, with **testImplementation**

```
dependencies {
testImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:1.0.0"
}
```

If you want to use `InstantTaskExecutorRule` for your UI or integration test cases(androidTest folder), use **androidTestImplementation**. that is:

`androidTestImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:1.0.0"`

And if you want to add for both, use **androidTestImplementation** & **testImplementation** that is:

`androidTestImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:1.0.0"`

`testImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:1.0.0"`

**For Android-X use below dependency:**

androidTestImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.0'

**OR**

testImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.0'

Comment: This shoild be the best answer

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @Kavita_p .... Android is mostly crazy and not developer friendly. testImplementation and androidTestImplementation should be defined if system needs to have dependency in Instrumentation test and Unit test... Wondering, when Google will make all these as developer friendly..!!!!  I found IOS development much more developer friendly... these thinks Really Sucks....

Comment: But if you use implementation, this library code will be present on your release APK. 
Which is not necessary or correct. If you want use on both, you should use both  androidTestImplementation and testImplementation.

Comment: Hi, @PauloPereira thanks for your input. Yes, you are right about including these libs in release APK. I will update my answer as well.

Comment: YES:!!!! for AndroidX use androidTestImplemention (not just testImplementation)

Answer (score 26):

for androidX migration, add

```
androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.0"
```

Comment: Latest version info can be found here - https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle

Answer (score 7):

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Please put this two dependencies in your gradle file,

```
dependencies {

    // Test helpers for LiveData
    testImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:1.0.0"

    // Test helpers for Room
    testImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.0.0"
}
```

Further information please go through this link,
[Android Architecture components integration guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is a conflict in some of the linked libraries.
I got around this, I used **blockingGet()** and **blockingFirst()**.

and, in the end, I used
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner.html#using-android-test-orchestrator

```
androidTestUtil 'com.android.support.test:orchestrator:1.0.1'
```

this is what you need!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes test dependency issues can be an issue of selecting the appropriate build variant, depending on your Gradle configuration. In my case, tests are configured for the debug build variant only.

Answer (score 0):

Changing from 'androidTestImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:1.0.0' to 2.0.0 somehow magically solved my problem.

Guessing it's because I use androidX.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33184788)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use like that.

```
implementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'
```

Changing `testImplementation` for `implementation`.

I am using Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1.