# Not able to import InstantTaskExecutorRule in my 'jUnit' test case even after adding 'core-testing' dependency - Android testing

Tags: unit-testing, viewmodel, android-testing, android-mvvm, mutablelivedata

I am writing test cases for my `LoginViewModel`. Where I want to perform `setValue()` operation on my `MutableLiveData`.

To avoid **Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked** Exception I am trying to add the following `Rule` in my ViewModel file inside **test folder**.

`@Rule
    public InstantTaskExecutorRule mInstantTaskExecutorRule = new InstantTaskExecutorRule();`

for that, I have added the following dependency:

```
androidTestImplementation 'android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1' as dependency.
```

But still, I am not able to import the `InstantTaskExecutorRule` in my LoginViewModelTest file. What could be the issue?

**Though it's getting imported in *androidTest* folder where we write integration or UI test cases! But not in *test* folder where we write jUnit test cases!**

Thank you in advance.

**Please refer the build. gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.login"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}

testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
def design = "28.0.0"
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$design"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$design"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$design"

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

androidTestImplementation 'android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1'

implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.9'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit-mock:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.8.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

def daggerVer = 2.16
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVer"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVer"
compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

//implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

def lifeCycle = "1.1.1"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifeCycle"
/*implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:$lifeCycle"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$lifeCycle"*/
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$lifeCycle"
implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
annotationProcessor 
"android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$lifeCycle"

implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

implementation 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.3'
implementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.4'
androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.18.3'
}
```

[image: importErrorScreenshot]

Comment: After investing some time on this, I have found one solution, refer the following answer,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56073388/6532155

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I need to add another dependency for `testImplementation` (the one we have is `androidTestImplementation`):
`testImplementation ("android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1")`